# Flatten request mapping hierarchy in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

With RestKit, I'm trying to create a request mapping that would convert a `payment` object into JSON. This object stores sub-payments, of which only one is valid. This valid payment is represented by the property `selectedPayment`. I think the typical approach for this is to use a relationship mapping however I don't want the `selectedPayment` to appear as a nested key. An example of the result of my current approach is below:

```
{
  "requestUserId" : "6",
  "payment" : {
    "selectedPayment" : {
      "amount" : "5",
      "id" : 70,
      "type" : "SOME_TYPE"
    }
  }
}
```

My desired output is the following:

```
{
  "requestUserId" : "6",
  "payment" : {
    "amount" : "5",
    "id" : 70,
    "type" : "SOME_TYPE"
  }
}
```

I have tried numerous options for my relationship mapping's destination key path: `@root`, `@parent`, `""`, `nil`. All of which have resulted in a crash (except `""`, which nests the selected payment under an empty key).

I could modify the attribute mappings of the request mapping that is used for `selectedPayment` to explicitly use `@root` or `@parent` but this would not be ideal as it would negatively affect other areas that mapping is used.

This seems like typical behaviour, converting a "deep" object representation into a "shallow" JSON representation, surely there is a straightforward way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a relationship mapping, use key paths in your single mapping, navigate into the property and then extract the keys that you seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a relationship mapping, instead use key paths in your single mapping to navigate into the property and extract the keys you want. So you would use `selectedPayment.amount`, `selectedPayment.id` and `selectedPayment.type` as the source key paths in the mapping and `amount`, `id` and `type` As the respective destination keys.

Comment: This is what I was hoping to avoid, and similar to what I meant by "I could modify the attribute mappings of the request mapping that is used for selectedPayment...". I have my various mappings split up to allow for reuse so changing one of them, or re-implementing it defeats that purpose. It would be nice if RestKit had a "prefix" property for mappings, which would essentially do what you're suggesting but in a more reusable way.